# SQL query execution returns a str type instead of composite vertex and edge type in Apache AGE

Tags: postgresql, pytest, apache-age

I am executing the following query in Python to return the list of all nodes stored in the Apache AGE.

```
with postgresql.cursor() as cursor:
    query = """SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$ MATCH (v) RETURN v $$) as (v agtype);""" 
    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])
```

But `row[0]` here is of the type `str` instead of `<class 'age.models.Node'>`. I need to access the id, label, and other properties of the node, which I could have easily done with `<class 'age.models.Node'>` by simply using `row[0].id` or `row[0].label`. I cannot do this with the str type.

I am currently trying to write unit test cases with `pytest` and `factories` from `pytest_postgresql`. It works properly when I run the same thing using `psycopg2`, and the expected data type is returned but fails with `pytest_postgresql`.

This is the code to set up the database.

```
postgresql_my_proc = factories.postgresql_proc()
postgresql_my = factories.postgresql('postgresql_my_proc')
```

Is it the issue with `pytest_postgresql`? Is it possible to fix this, and is there some workaround to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Apache AGE Python Driver](https://github.com/rhizome-ai/apache-age-python). This way, retrieving node IDs and labels would be very easy, as shown in the following sample:

```
cursor = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n")
for row in cursor:
    vertex = row[0]
    print(vertex)
    print(vertex.id, vertex.label, vertex["name"])
```

More samples can be seen [here](https://github.com/rhizome-ai/apache-age-python/blob/main/samples/apache-age-note.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen an example from the apache age GitHub documentation and they are using another way to retrieve these things.

### Single result column

```
cursor = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:Person {name: %s) RETURN n", params('Andy',))
for row in cursor:
  vertex = row[0]
  print(vertex.id, vertex["name"], vertex) # row has id, label, properties
```

### Multi result columns

```
cursor = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN label(n), n.name", cols=['label VARCHAR', 'name'])
for row in cursor:
    label = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    print(label, name)
```

you can get more information from this file.

[Github File](https://github.com/rhizome-ai/apache-age-python/blob/main/samples/apache-age-note.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

You query may be returning a `str` type because you didn't load the AGE python drivers. You should visit the AGE python samples on github using this [link](https://github.com/rhizome-ai/apache-age-python/tree/main/samples) to get an insight on what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could share the output and other parts of the code instead of a snippet.

However, to help solve this. Firstly, make sure the Models module is imported using `import age.models`.
Secondly, the Python Driver has functions that simplifies the process for querying AGE using Python and I suggest you should use that, some of the methods include `execCypher()`, `age.connect()` , etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use psycopg2 to query postgres database using python scripts.

Connect to postgres running instance using:

```
import psycopg2, age
GRAPH_NAME = 'graph'
conn = psycopg2.connect(
host = 'localhost',
port = '5432',
dbname = 'agedb',
user = 'zainab',
password = '167984'
)
age.setUpAge(conn, GRAPH_NAME)
```

Then you can execute the following script to retrieve all the vertices' label, id, properties:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
query = """SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.cypher('%s', $$ MATCH (v) RETURN v $$) as (v 
agtype);""" %s (GRAPH_NAME,)

try:

    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
except Exception as ex:
    print(type(ex), ex)
for row in rows:
    print(row[0].label, row[0].id, row[0].properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible ways to tackle the issue that you're facing.

You may want to explicitly cast the datatype to your desired type. e.g. if the data being returned is of type string and you want the output to be an instance of  'age.models.Node' you might have to manually instantiate an instance and populate it with the relevant data.

You can also inspect the result by printing out the entire row beforehand.